# Quick way to copy elements in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, pointers

I want to change

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<100; j++) {
      A[i][j] = A_new[i][j]
   }
}
```

into something a lot quicker involving pointers. However, I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I've tried something like this

```
double *first = A;
double *second = A_new;
first = second;
```

but that hasn't worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of any method you try will depend on a number of factors such as the intelligence of the compiler in optimizing this kind of operation, and on the target processor you are using. Some compilers produce faster code using pointers, and others produce faster code using array subscripts. The best way to find out whether one method is faster than another is to code them both, run them, and time how long they take to run. This can be done using a library timer function. You could also examine the generated assembly language code to see which version produces tighter code.

The method you tried, shown below

```
double *first = A;
double *second = A_new;
first = second;
```

doesn't work because the statement `first = second;` simply sets the `first` pointer to point to the start of the `second` array. No array elements are actually copied.

In C, a 2-dimensional array is arranged in memory as though it were a 1-dimensional array with each row occurring in memory immediately after the preceding row. So one minor optimization would be to perform the operation in a single loop, instead of a set of nested loops, as follows:

```
double A[100][100];
double A_new[100][100];

for (i = 0; i < (100 * 100); i++) {
      A[i] = A_new[i];
}
```

This might run faster than your original version because there is only one loop, and one loop counter, for the program to keep track of.

The pointer version of this would look like the following:

```
double A[100][100];
double A_new[100][100];
double *destination = A;
double *source = A_new;

for (i = 0; i < (100 * 100); i++) {
      *destination++ = *source++;
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, you would need to code both and time them to find out which one runs faster.